# NoReverseMatch at when calling url

Tags: django

I can't work out why im getting this error
`NoReverseMatch at /` when calling `<a href="{% url 'show_token_details'  token.id %}">`

```
def show_token_details(request,token_id):
    token = Token.objects.get(token_id == token_id)

    return render(request, 'ecommerceproductdetails.html', {})
```

```
path("token/<int:token_id>", views.show_token_details, name='show_token_details'),
```

What am I missing here?

Updated:

```
Reverse for 'show_token_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['token/(?P<token_id>[0-9]+)\\Z', 'token/(?P<token_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']
```

Thanks

Comment: please post the complete error message

Comment: Sorry. That would have been helpful. post updated

Comment: "with arguments '('',)' not found."    means always that the url argument is empty. In your case token.id in the url tag is empty

Comment: hmm, im not sure why `token.id` is empty. But thanks for pointing that out. Ill take a look at my template

Comment: check by just printing it in the html file like "****{{ token.id }}***"

Comment: if it is empty, check what context you handover to the render() call for that template

Comment: I have `<a href="{% url 'show_token_details'  token.id %}">` within a for loop. `{% for item in token %}` So should token.id actualy be` token.token.id`?

Comment: it should be item.id

Comment: Then use `item.id`

Comment: I think the cause of the problem is `context` you aren't supplying any `context` to the HTML page. also if you have a multi-app application then use the app name with the URL like this `<a href="{% url 'app_name:show_token_details'  token.id %}">`